# How to place value at random locations in an array using Math.random?

Tags: java, arrays, random

i have an array called Events.

```
String[] Events = new String[20];
```

How can I write a method to place 10 random events into this array using math.random() only? My attempt to solving the question is this: I'm new and still learning moving from python to java, stress much.

```
public static void AddRandomEvents(Events[] event) {
    for(int i = 0; i < event.length; i++){
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() + 10) + 1;
        System.out.println(event[rand]);
    }
}
```

I had a class called events and thats why its Events[]

Any help or contribution would be helpful. Thanks.

Also adding, I'm placing 10 random events from this array

```
String[] names = {"Wedding", "Birthday", "Funeral","Clubbing","Anniversary", "Volunteer", "Job fair"};
```

to the events array, how to? thanks

Comment: do you want to set 10 values of event array from names array? in that case duplicate entry may happen. .right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.util.Random also offers methods to generate numbers which are pseudorandom, uniformly distributed values. In order to pick 10 random events out of the `event` array, nextInt(int n) method can be helpful.

```
    public static void addRandomEvents(Events[] events) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int randomEventIndex = random.nextInt(eventNames.length);
            String randomEventName = eventNames[randomEventIndex];
            String randomEventTime = new Date().toString();
            int randomPriority = random.nextInt(events.length);
            Events randomEvent = new Events(randomEventTime, randomEventName, randomPriority);
            events[i] = randomEvent;
        }
    }
```

This method can be invoked in this manner:

```
    static String[] eventNames = {"Wedding", "Birthday", "Funeral","Clubbing","Anniversary", "Volunteer", "Job fair"};
    Events[] events = new Events[10];
    addRandomEvents(events);
```

Comment: the question is not asking to pick 10 random event. it is putting 10 random events into an array of events from another array :)

Comment: i also added a few lines to clarify  the question just in case.

Comment: Just to clarify, we have a source array of events, and a target array which has to be populated with random 10 events from the source array ?

Comment: Yes i just added it. the source array is names

Comment: so  a) A random event name has to be picked from the eventNames array.  b) pick an event time. i have set it to current date, which you are free to modify according to your requirements. c) pick a priority. i have created a random priority in the example and you can change it as per your needs. d) Instantiate a random event object, supplying the values chosen in steps a, b and c.  Finally, store this event object in the target array reference  passed into the `addRandomEvents(Events[] events)` method. 
Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks this was helpful